# A problem with understanding in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, word-in-context

everyone

I read this fragment in a book. I don't know its author and title.
Could you help me to understand the bolded fragments?

"When my father used to get angry with me, I hated him for it. **When I was young, it was my school work. As I got older, it was the decisions I made.** When I started working for him at the family firm, I couldn’t do anything right. ‘You sent out the wrong order.’ ‘You used the wrong leather.’ ‘That colour you chose for that bag is disgusting.’ The more often it happened, the more my feelings of love turned into something else, **hard-edged and bitter**, until that was all that was left."

Comment: It was those things (how he was doing in school. the decisions he made) that made his father angry.

Comment: **bitter** you could find in a dictionary.  **hard-edged** is a figurative use that implies defensiveness and resentment.  His feelings for his father had a hard edge.

Comment: Thanks, ye I know 'bitter' but I was curious if it changes the meaning with 'hard-edged'

Comment: I do think **bitter** puts a particular spin on **hard-edged**.  In some contexts, "hard-edged" can mean "harshly unsentimental" but when coupled with bitterness it suggests there's an underlying anger, and the hard-edgedness is not a coldly truthful point-of-view devoid of sentimentality.